# Something I don't understand about Epiphany

Tags: 14.04, gnome, firefox, epiphany

I like to try out different web browsers, on windows sometimes I had 4 or 5 of them. Still that Firefox is my all-time favourite I was thinking about trying out the default Epiphany browser on Ubuntu 14.04, but I just can't figure it out how to open new tabs or get bookmarks.
Is there no such option or what? If I'm wrong can you give some instructions how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epiphany uses a grid view interface since it is considered easier to use on a touchscreen.

[image]

From this [source](http://blogs.gnome.org/xan/2011/12/04/a-new-design-for-epiphany-web/):

- The tab bar might be gone, but we’ll still offer a convenient, and we think improved, way of switching between pages. All the currently and recently opened pages are visible in the overview (the new start page), and we’ll provide a way of switching between them with the mouse or keyboard shortcuts. You can see an early animated mockup of this in this video of the gnome design youtube channel

(the link has a video)

The manual has this to say about bookmarks:

- [add a bookmark](https://help.gnome.org/users/epiphany/stable/bookmark-add.html.en): Select the menu at the top-right of the window, then Bookmarks ▸ Add Bookmark… or press Ctrl+D to add a bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

To open a new tab in Epiphany, press <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd>. When there's only a single tab, the tab bar is invisible.

To jump from tab to tab, use <kbd>Ctrl+PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+PgDn</kbd>, to close the current tab, press <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>